# java.lang.illegalArgumentException when calling pumpEvents using reflection

Tags: java, swing, reflection

I'm trying to make modal frame in Java Applet such like shown here: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/Showthegivenframeasmodaltothespecifiedowner.htm. This code have start() function, that looks like

```
public void start() throws Exception {
  Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("java.awt.Conditional");
  Object conditional = Proxy.newProxyInstance(clazz.getClassLoader(), new Class[] { clazz },
      this);
  Method pumpMethod = Class.forName("java.awt.EventDispatchThread").getDeclaredMethod(
      "pumpEvents", new Class[] { clazz });
  pumpMethod.setAccessible(true);
  pumpMethod.invoke(Thread.currentThread(), new Object[] { conditional });
}.
```

When I call

```
 pumpMethod.invoke(Thread.currentThread(), new Object[] { conditional });
```

I have following exception:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at wizard.ModalFrameUtil.showAsModal(ModalFrameUtil.java:136)
    at wizard.WizardCore.showWizardFrame(WizardCore.java:206)
    at SelfRegistrationApplet$1.run(SelfRegistrationApplet.java:55)
    at SelfRegistrationApplet$1.run(SelfRegistrationApplet.java:35)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at SelfRegistrationApplet.RunSelfRegistrationApplet(SelfRegistrationApplet.java:32)
    at SelfRegistrationApplet.init(SelfRegistrationApplet.java:26)
    at sun.applet.AppletPanel.run(AppletPanel.java:424)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: object is not an instance of declaring class
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at wizard.ModalFrameUtil$EventPump.start(ModalFrameUtil.java:80)
    at wizard.ModalFrameUtil.showAsModal(ModalFrameUtil.java:133)
    ... 8 more
```

Could You please tell what is wrong in this invocation and how to avoid this exception?

Comment: The first parameter for the __invoke__ method should be the object on which to call it. Here you pass __Thread.currentThread()__. Is that correct? I would rather use an instance of __java.awt.EventDispatchThread__ instead...

Comment: **@reef**, thank you for your answer. But I have another one - how I can get an instance of `java.awt.EventDispatchThread`? Using reflection again?

Comment: I fixed my problem with invocation. It's reason was in thread class. I added code for getting an object of java.awt.EventDispatchThread class and now call `invoke()` metod using this object: `Constructor constructor = Class.forName("java.awt.EventDispatchThread").
                    getDeclaredConstructor(ThreadGroup.class, name.getClass(), eventQueue.getClass());
            constructor.setAccessible(true);
            Object eventDispatchThread = constructor.newInstance(threadGroup, name, eventQueue);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it is saying is that the `Thread` object returned by `Thread.currentThread()` is not an instance of `EventDispatchThread`.

The way to avoid the problem is to find out what the class of that object really is, and use *that* class to obtain the `Method` object.  (You should be able to find out what it is by printing the object you get from `Thread.currentThread().getClass()` at the place where you are trying to invoke the method.

---

The Javadoc for `invoke` this says this:

> "Throws `IllegalArgumentException` - if the method is an instance method and the specified object argument is not an instance of the class or interface declaring the underlying method (or of a subclass or implementor thereof); if the number of actual and formal parameters differ; if an unwrapping conversion for primitive arguments fails; or if, after possible unwrapping, a parameter value cannot be converted to the corresponding formal parameter type by a method invocation conversion."

My reading of your code is that you have the right number and type of actual arguments, so it must be an issue with the thread class.

Answer (score 0):

AWT and swing GUIs are single-threaded the event dispatch thread is a special thread where all GUI operations should be run. It's likely that your method is not invoked on the GUI Thread. Make sure that you invoke your method on the event dispatch thread, you can do so by calling it like this

```
SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable(){public void run(){mymethod();}})
```

Note: The javadocs do not contain `java.awt.EventDispatchThread` so you likely depend on some implementation detail. You can use a subclass of `java.awt.EventQueue` and `Toolkit.getSystemEventQueue()` instead.